# How do i get the URL without the link text of my link field

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a link field with the machine name of field_link. I need to use the URL only in my `views-view-field--NAME.html.twig` file. I'm having trouble figuring out how to separate the url from the link text.

`{{fields.field_link.content}}` prints out the URL and the link text.

How do I only get the URL? The context I would like to use it in would be:

```
    <a href={{ ??? }}><h3>{{ fields.title.content }}</h3>
    <p>{{ fields.field_link.content|striptags|trim }}</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ fields.field_link.content[0]['#url']|render }}
```

OR extract it in php and create a variable from $result and use it in your twig file:

```
$link = '<a href="www.something.com">Click here</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $link, $result);

if (!empty($result)) {
# Found a link.
echo $result['href'][0];
}
```